# How can I secure all web server in a multi domain (Active Directory Forest) environment using single SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, active-directory, subdomain

I have a multi-domain environment (active directory forest), e.g. **subdomain1.mydomain.com**, **subdomain2.mydomain.com** where **mydomain.com** is root AD domain (GC) and **subdomain1** and **subdomain2** are child domains under **mydomain.com**. In total I have four subdomains and more can be added if required.

I have web servers like **server1.subdomain1.mydomain.com** and **server2.subdomain2.mydomain.com**. I need to get an SSL certificate to secure these server and also any servers which are added in future.

My questions are:

- Can I have a multi-level wildcard certificate (***.*.mydomain.com**)
  to secure all servers?
- Do I need to have individual certificates for
  each subdomains (e.g. ***.subdomain1.mydomain.com**,
  ***.subdomain2.mydomain.com**)?
- Is UCC certificate suitable for this requirement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I have a multi-level wildcard certificate (*.*.mydomain.com) to secure all servers?

No, multi-level wildcards will not be accepted by the browsers.

> Do I need to have individual certificates for each subdomains (e.g. *.subdomain1.mydomain.com, *.subdomain2.mydomain.com)?

There is no need to have individual certificates. You can have a single certificate which covers multiple hosts

> Is UCC certificate suitable for this requirement?

Probably yes.

Comment: Thanks very much Steffen for your quick response. I will check further on 2nd/3rd oprtions for my requirements and get back.

Comment: We have decided to go with UCC certificate.